Step back step forward algorithm for A108442

Let $a(n)$ be A108442. Here generating function is $\frac{1}{1-zA(z)}$ where
$$
A(z) = 1 + z(A(z))^2 + z(A(z))^3.
$$
Also
$$
a(n) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{2n-k}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-k} \binom{2n-k}{i}\binom{3n-2k-i-1}{2n-k-1}.
$$
Start with vector $\nu$ of fixed length $2m$ with elements $\nu_i = 1$ (that is, $\nu = \{1, 1, \dotsc, 1\}$), reserve $t$ as an empty vector of fixed length $m$, set $t_1 = 1$ and for $i$ from $1$ to $m-1$, for $j$ from $i+1$ to $2m-i$ consecutively apply
$$
\nu_{j} := \nu_j + \nu_{j-1} + \nu_{j+1}.
$$
We also need to apply $t_{i+1} = \nu_{i+1}$ (after ending each cycle for $j$).

I conjecture that after the whole transform we have
$$
t_n = a(n).
$$
Here is the PARI/GP program to check it numerically:
a(n) = sum(k=1, n, k/(2*n-k)*sum(i=0, n-k, binomial(2*n-k, i)*binomial(3*n-2*k-i-1, 2*n-k-1)))
upto1(n) = my(v1); v1 = vector(2*n, i, 1); v2 = vector(n, i, 0); v2[1] = 1; for(i=1, n-1, for(j=i+1, 2*n-i, v1[j] += v1[j-1] + v1[j+1]); v2[i+1] = v1[i+1]); v2
test1(n) = vector(n, i, a(i)) == upto1(n)

Is there a way to prove it?

I think you have a typo in your expression for $v_j$. In general after writing down the recurrence (perhaps in two variables) it should be possible to get somewhere with generating functions.

There is no typo. To check it, see the program on PARI/GP.
